# R function to sort column by string length then by alphabet?

Tags: r, sorting

I would like to sort one column in my data frame by string length first then by alphabet, I tried code below:

```
#sort column by string length then alphabet
GSN[order(nchar(GSN[,3]),GSN[,3]),]
```

But I got error

```
Error in nchar(GSN[, 3]) : 'nchar()' requires a character vector
```

My data looks like:

```
    Flowcell Lane    barcode         sample         plate row column
314       NA   NA AACAGACATT   LD06_7620SDS GSN1_Hind384D   B      4
307       NA   NA  AACAGCACT   LG10_2688SDS GSN1_Hind384D   C      3
289       NA   NA     AACCTC  U09_105007SDS GSN1_Hind384D   A      1
232       NA   NA AACGACCACC         13_232 GSN1_Hind384C   H      5
10        NA   NA AACGCACATT          13_10 GSN1_Hind384A   B      2
165       NA   NA      AACGG         13_165 GSN1_Hind384B   E      9
```

I would like to sort "barcode" column.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add another column to your data frame that contains the number of characters in the barcode, then sort in the usual way.

```
GSN <- transform(GSN, n=nchar(as.character(barcode)))

GSN[with(GSN, order(n, barcode)), ]
```

It appears that the issue you were having is because R thinks that `barcode` is a factor rather than a character vector, so `nchar()` is invalid. Converting it to character via `as.character()` solves this.

Answer (score 3):

I wish to add a tidyverse solution

```
library(tidyverse)

GSN_sorted =  GSN %>%
    mutate(barcode = as.character(barcode)) %>%
    arrange(str_length(barcode), barcode)
```

Note the factor to character conversion originally pointed out by Alex A.

Comment: For those interested in loading discrete packages (instead of all of tidyverse), this solution just requires dplyr and stringr.